# Eclipse ADT giving wrong smallest width selector

Tags: android, eclipse, android-selector

I'm building an app and I'm adjusting the sizes between two specific tablets: Sony XPeria Tablet Z and Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 10.1.

I created a template for the XPeria in AVD Manager like this:
[image: Tablet Z template]

Now, on the layout view, I click on the small "android sheet" on the top left of the design window [image] and click on "Create new...".

There I see the option "sw901dp" in the new window to set it as a selector [image]

Now, I also have a sw800dp folder for Galaxy Tab 3. The problem is that during runtime, the XPeria Tablet is returning the values from sw800dp instead from sw901dp. During the preview it fetches from the right folder. Explaining this will also allow to explain why Galaxy Tab is fetching from sw800dp in preview and sw600dp in runtime...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, doing the math, Eclipse seems to be right.

Given these dimensions (10.1", 1920x1200), the screen has a density of 224 dpi, which is closest to tvdpi. 1200px at tvdpi is indeed 901dp, so that works out fine.

Do `getResources().getDisplayMetrics()` to see what Android thinks of the actual device. In particular, you're interested in `densityDpi`, `widthPixels` and `heightPixels`. It's possible that the device targets a different density than the one suggested by Eclipse, which might lead to problems like this.

Comment: Density DPI is 240
WidthPixels 1920
HeightPixels 1128

Guess that is the height that is wrong... Maybe because of the status bar?

Comment: The height is not the problem (and yes, it's the status bar). The density, however is hdpi and not tvdpi - change it in your device configuration (on the right -> Screen density) and that should fix it. (1200px is 800dp on an hdpi screen)